# Simple web3 PHP - BlockChain contract communication

Tags: php, blockchain

i have problem with communication with blockchain.
I use simple web3 vendor to communication but i have a problem with it.

Data looks something like

```
^ array:10 [
  "orderId" => "c9233823-b5f2-4de9-aa3b-fb8f60e578f4x"
  "paymentId" => "abcd1324-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
  "status" => "sent"
  "createdAt" => "2023-08-30 11:31:25"
  "totalQuantity" => "10"
  "clientJson" => "{"id":1,"name":"Restoranto milano s.k."}"
  "orderProductsJson" => "[{"id":1,"productName":"Kubek z pudzianem","productCategoryName":"Naczynia","quantity":10,"availability":10000,"totalPrice":"{\"netPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"grossPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatAmount\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatRate\":\"0\"}","unitPrice":"{\"netPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"grossPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatAmount\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatRate\":\"0\"}"}]"
  "totalProductPriceJson" => ""{\"netPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"grossPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatAmount\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatRate\":\"0\"}""
  "subTotalPriceJson" => ""{\"netPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"grossPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatAmount\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatRate\":\"0\"}""
  "deliveryPriceJson" => ""{\"netPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"grossPrice\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatAmount\":{\"amount\":\"0\",\"currency\":\"PLN\"},\"vatRate\":\"0\"}""
]
```

Abi

```
        {
          "inputs": [
            {
              "components": [
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "orderId",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "paymentId",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "status",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "createdAt",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "totalQuantity",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "clientJson",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "orderProductsJson",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "totalProductPriceJson",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "subTotalPriceJson",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "deliveryPriceJson",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ],
              "internalType": "struct Order",
              "name": "_order",
              "type": "tuple"
            }
          ],
          "name": "setOrder",
          "outputs": [],
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        },
```

And this is my php code

```
      $contractAddress = '0x05d91B9031A655d08E654177336d08543ac4B711';
      $sweb3 = new SWeb3('http://172.33.0.11:8545');
      $sweb3->setPersonalData($contractAddress, '8f2a55949038a9610f50fb23b5883af3b4ecb3c3bb792cbcefbd1542c692be63');
      $noonce = $sweb3->getNonce($contractAddress);
      $sweb3->chainId = '300300';

      $extraParams = [
        'from' => '0xFE3B557E8Fb62b89F4916B721be55cEb828dBd73',
        'gasLimit' => '0x1ffffffffffffffff',
        'nonce' => '0x099'
      ];
      //$wallet = new Wallet($sweb3, $privateKey);
      $contract = new SWeb3_Contract($sweb3, $contractAddress, $this->orderAbi);
      //dd(json_encode($data));
      $result = $contract->send('setOrder', $data, $extraParams);
```

And i take a little problem with it, when i try use i catch a problem

```
^ {#2756
  +"jsonrpc": "2.0"
  +"id": 0
  +"error": {#2772
    +"code": -32602
    +"message": "Invalid params"
  }
}
```

i try also
getOrder with other ABI and i get something like

```
b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02€\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02À\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05à\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Someone can told me why i doing wrong?

Comment: First off, I don't believe that you need to set the contract bytecode, that's only done to deploy contracts. If you're interacting with a deployed contract you only need the ABI. Second: your parameters are incorrect, you're passing in an associated array, but your inputs expect an `_order` object input with tupled fields. The tests have some hints on how to properly pass these parameters https://github.com/drlecks/Simple-Web3-Php/blob/master/Test/test.php

Comment: thats true, i only add it for test, so i delete it from here.

Comment: If i good understand your words and the tests
The tests is not actuall for other code in this package, beacuse the EncodeData get array no stdClass but this is not a problem, problem is when i use 

$contract->send('setOrder', $data);

the encodeGroup is to execute, with the tuple but in my case i must overide the class beacuse is not support component in inputs array (ABI).

But after this changes the data looks good, but still Invalid params :/

Comment: Your `$data` does not mirror the ABI you posted. It should have an `_order` tuple. Take a look at `EncodeGroup` https://github.com/drlecks/Simple-Web3-Php/blob/master/Core/ABI.php#L280 you can see (try step-by-step debugging) how it fails to match the ABI inputs to the data array that you supply. There's no `_order` input which encapsulates the tuples. I'm pretty sure none of the parameters you're passing in are actually encoded into the payload.

Comment: When i use _order
````
$newData['_order'] = $data;
````
and take the $newData to EncodeGroup i take problem with stdClass 

https://github.com/drlecks/Simple-Web3-Php/blob/0bac2b4e214f381a7639f69a0fd8b4cb07dbdd2a/Core/ABI.php#L317
in this line

i don't know what i should to do beacuse when i go to inside the _order then the first index dosent exist

Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$orderId

What i should change to have good parameters to tuple parameters.

Comment: You could try casting it to an object if it's expecting an object, use `(object)$data`, but it might not be enough, it might need a specific class, but casting should give you more information on what it's expecting.

Comment: This is not a problem with data casting, the issue here is now about the levels of data, tuple as far as I know requires setOrder($string, $string, $string etc..)

And will this method do that?

And here the problem is not for me to change the code to handle std, array

but I don't know exactly what the result of this data should look like. Because this is key for me. What is to be toHex() later?

Comment: Something like this
      $newData['_order'] = (object) $data;
      $json = json_encode($newData);
      $json = str_replace("\\", '', $json);
      $dataToSend = '0x'.Utils::toHex($json);

is not ready to send?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to deal with encoding, that's handled by the `Contract::send` method, you need to pass in the right structure and types. What error does merely casting to an object do?

Comment: I have really bad contact with it, i have a typescript code where add to blockchain work, i copy generated 'data' code and i paste it to my code, before in this place 
https://github.com/drlecks/Simple-Web3-Php/blob/0bac2b4e214f381a7639f69a0fd8b4cb07dbdd2a/Core/SWeb3_Contract.php#L76

And still invalid params :/